# lambda endpoint prediction failed with error can't convert string to float

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

I am facing the issue in getting the prediction from sagemaker xgboost endpoint. When I feed the transformed data in endpoint like:

```
response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,ContentType='text/csv',Body = csv_buffer.getvalue())
```

throwing the error :

> can not convert string to float.

Could you please help me out what I am missing.